# Ubuntu sftp default save permissions issue

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, sftp, file-permissions, chmod

I have a server running Ubuntu 8.04 LTS with sftp running on it. My problem is that when I access the server with sftp (using the username of one of my admin accounts, not 'root') and upload a file it's saved with the permissions `rwx------`. I then have to manually change the permissions using `sudo chmod 755 filename`.

Is there any way to set the default save permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Change the Subsystem line in your sshd_config file:

```
Subsystem sftp /bin/sh -c 'umask 0022; /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server'
```